# How to efficiently wrap a C-library into Swift class

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, operator-overloading, wrapper

I want to wrap a C-library (handling some NumberTheory related items, which I wrote some 20 years ago in C) into Swift. I started writing an Objective-C wrapper for this C-library, end then wrote a Swift derived class from the Objective-C wrapper.
Since Objective-C doesn't allow me to write overloaded methods/operators, I want to accomplish this in Swift. The C-library in question has API-calls starting with 'numthe' and a libnumthe.a and a "numthe.h" include file. The Objective-C wrapper/class is called NumTheObjC and the Swift class NumThe

Currently I've the following code for the NumTheObjC.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import "numthe.h"
@interface NumTheObjC : NSObject
{
    numthe_prime nPrime;     // Holds a numthe_prime number type instance.
    numthe_perfect nPerfect; // Holds a numthe_perfect number type instance.
    //... more numthe types/structure instances here.
}
-(id)init;                  // Default initializer
-(id)init:(NSString *)str;  // Initialize from string-value.
-(void)add:(NumTheObjC *)op;                                     // a += b
+(NumTheObjC *)add:(NumTheObjC *)left right:(NumTheObjC *)right; // x = a + b
-(void)setFromInt:(signed int)nrInt;        // Initialize/set from int.
-(void)setFromLong:(signed long)nrLong;     // Initialize/set from long.
-(void)setFromUInt:(unsigned int)nrUInt;    // Initialize/set from uint.
-(void)setFromULong:(unsigned long)nrULong; // Initialize/set from ulong.
@end
```

And for the Swift wrapper I came up with the NumThe.swift file:

```
class NumThe : NumTheObjC {
    init(nr: Int) {
        super.init()
        setFromInt(nr)
    }
    init(nr: UInt) {
        super.init()
        setFromUInt(nr)
    }
    init(strNr: String) {
        super.init(strNr)
    }
    //... more overloaded 'constructors/initializers here ...
}
//-- Overloaded operator a + b
func + (inout left: NumThe, right: NumThe) -> NumTheObjC {
    return NumTheObjC.add(left, right: right)
}
//-- Overloaded operator +=
func += (inout left: NumTheObjC, right: NumThe) {
    return left.add(right)
}
```

Still some thoughts and questions remain, viz.:
1. I'm wondering if the above is the best approach to accomplish my goal.
2. Should the signature of all methods use NumTheObjC parameter-types instead of NumThe?
3. I can't seem to figure out how to let the above overloaded operator for 'a + b' return a NumThe instance instead of the NumTheObjC-instance.
4. Is there a more efficient approach in using C++ like templates/types to get all kinds of overloaded methods/operators?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions/tips!

Answer (score 0):

*1. I'm wondering if the above is the best approach to accomplish my goal.*

You can need a new subclass `NumThe`. You can add new init() via extension of `NumTheObjC`. See [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) for more info

*2. Should the signature of all methods use NumTheObjC parameter-types instead of NumThe?*

If you use extension then you do not need to change your parameter types

*3. I can't seem to figure out how to let the above overloaded operator for 'a + b' return a NumThe instance instead of the NumTheObjC-instance.*

Solution for point 1 ('extension') should resolve this too

*4. Is there a more efficient approach in using C++ like templates/types to get all kinds of overloaded methods/operators?*

I don't think it is possible. Again check out [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11), the `Preprocessor Directives` section.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for the references to extension-mechanism, I haven't look at this yet. Still I'm faced with the following code (see also item 3) above:<br>
var nt1 = NumThe(12), nt2 = NumThe(45)<br>
var nt3 = nt1 + nt2<br>
I want the nt3 to be a NumThe-instance, but instead its a NumTheObjC instance. How do I accomplish this?